# Is 0.0.0.0 a valid IP address?

Tags: networking, ip

Is 0.0.0.0 a valid IP address? I want my program to be able to store it as an indication that no address is in use, but this won't work if it's actually valid.

Comment: why?  what possible application could this have?

Comment: Did you try to ping it ?

Comment: A list of reserved IP addresses is [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses)

Comment: So, I think this is a legitimate question and is related to programming.  For example, if you are storing an IP address, you might want to represent "no IP address available" as zero, which you couldn't do if `0.0.0.0` was a valid IP address.

Comment: This was the "Who opens wikipedia faster" contest. All answers refer it.

Comment: [This question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/56406/8499) has answers that explain about the IPv4 `0.0.0.0` address.

Answer (score 62):

It is *valid* inasmuch as it contains four octets, each within the range 0 through 255 inclusive. However, it is not *usable* as a real IP address.

[RFC1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700) <sup>(a)</sup> states that `0.0.0.0/8` (`0.<anything>.<anything>.<anything>`) is reserved as a source address only. You can get into situation where it appears you have this address but that's normally because no address has been assigned to you (by DHCP, for example).

See also [Wikipedia entry on IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Although this RFC is now considered obsolete, it is still correct in terms of the given behaviour. Its replacement, https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml, still has the same text detailing use of the 0.0.0.0 address.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it is in fact an IP address -- it's just reserved. Just because it's reserved does not mean it's not an IP address.

Comment: Well, I took "valid" to mean usable. It's certainly a legal IP address since each of the octets are in the range 0 thru 255. Adjusting answer to clarify.

Comment: I wanted to make sure my previous comment was correct so I did some reading. RFC 1700 states: "There are five classes of IP addresses: Class A through Class E." In RFC 790, it states 0.rrr.rrr.rrr is under the "Class A Network." Therefore, since 0.0.0.0 is a Class A address, it is an IP address. If any of these statements are wrong feel free to correct me.

Comment: @Daniel, I don't think _any_ of your statements are wrong, we just had different ideas as to what "valid" meant, which is why I clarified.

Comment: RFC1700 was obsoleted by RFC3232 that states  'RFC 1700 is
 obsolete, and its values are incomplete and in some cases may be
 wrong." .

Comment: Well in fact real source reference is IANA : https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml that clearly states in a table that it can't be used as destination.

Answer (score 10):

Lets look at the Question being asked here by the OP.

> Is 0.0.0.0 a valid IP address?

Yes. This is technically a valid IP address, and the other answers describe many various uses of it (I am not going to repost [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) links here ... or maybe I am).

As such I believe [paxdiablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655777/1441160) above is the most correct, but lets look at the context of your question as well.

> I want my program to be able to store it as an indication that no address is in use, but this won't work if it's actually valid.

This entirely depends on your use case. Given that this is a programmers forum, lets consider that perspective.

If your software is storing actual internet addresses - server locations, visitors to your website, replication/mirror or backup sites, web service or database servers etc. - then this will be perfectly valid. No machine on the internet will ever have this address assigned, nor will it ever resolve to a valid connection.

If on the other hand you are writing firewall or router firmware, then this address does take on special meaning; default route, accept any IP source/destination, block all IP source/destination, fall-trough catch-all, etc. as outlined by everyone else. However, let me point out that if you are coding on this level you should have a good enough understanding of network protocols so as to not need to ask this question in the first place.

I am therefore going to assume that most people viewing this question fall into the first category, and suggest that this **is a perfectly valid way of storing a null, empty or missing IP address**, if there is some reason that an actual `null` value cannot be used. Even if you neglect validation checking and your software does try to connect to this IP address, it will simply not be able to make a connection.

Comment: If nothing else, the trouble with allowing a valid value to be overloaded as a flag item is that it encourages bad habits. It can be a real problem too though: the code is reused elsewhere where the overloaded value is meaningful, now there are subtle bugs.

Answer (score 8):

The `0.0.0.0` is used to bind all IPv4 interfaces. So it's a special value just like `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is an IP address **but** it is reserved.

> 0.0.0.0/8 - **Addresses** in this block refer to source hosts on "this"
>      network.  Address 0.0.0.0/32 may be used as a source address for this
>      host on this network; other addresses within 0.0.0.0/8 may be used to
>      refer to specified hosts on this network

Answer (score 3):

It's reserved as the [default route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route) address.

It's common to see this via ipconfig when no address has been assigned to you.

Comment: You are thinking of 0.0.0.0/0 which is VERY different from 0.0.0.0/32.

Answer (score 1):

for all intents and purposes, yes. Each of the four numbers separated by the period have a value ranging from 0-255, so 0.0.0.0 is technically valid.

I don't think that there would be anyone in the world who actually has that IP though.

EDIT: okay, it is reserved for the default route, but it is still valid.

Comment: It's reserved for the default route.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in your application to represent that it does not have an IP address, Microsoft also uses 0.0.0.0 when the machine has no IP address.

the "Valid" scenarios talked about above are dependent on the specific scenarios where they have nothing to do with your application.

Comment: you can but you should not. because it is an ip address that can be addressed and has a function.

Comment: @TheSurrican It is an IP address that cannot be addressed and has a function.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a Network Whois query can also produce output that is quite helpful.
Example:
**http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=0.0.0.0?showDetails=true**

> Comment: The address 0.0.0.0 may only be used as the address of an outgoing packet when a computer is learning which IP address it should use. It is never used as a destination address. Addresses starting with "0." are sometimes used for broadcasts to directly connected devices.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have covered, 0.0.0.0 is a legal and valid for some purposes IP address.

If all values in a range are legal values, then any flag items you want to define must come from somewhere else. Otherwise you will overload a legal value with the meaning of a flag, and when using the overloaded value it won't be 100% possible to determine whether the legal value or the flag meaning was intended. This will lead to bugs which must be solved with a re-factor which can be an expensive endeavour.

Overloading legal values happens all the time, IP address and MAC addresses (yes, 00:00:00:00:00:00 is legal and allocated) are some of the most common victims.

Coincidentally, I am working on a system (not ethernet/IP based) now where the length of a frame is capped at about 40 bytes. Since a byte can represent lengths of 0 - 255 bytes, and the max length is 40 bytes, I can use some of the unused aka non-legal values (252 to 255) to represent flag items. These in-band flags are okay because there is no overloading.

Comment: "_I am working on a system now where the length of a frame is capped at about 40 bytes._" Which data-link protocol caps a frame at 40 bytes? Usually, there is a minimum frame length. For example, ethernet requires a _minimum_ frame length of 64 bytes, and it will pad the payload to achieve that.

Comment: @RonMaupin It's not an ethernet/IP system, it just happened to be a real life example of in-band flagging I had at hand.

Answer (score 0):

of course it is.
it will not be valid for a single host on a network however. it is in the broadcast range for the local network. read here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700