# IP address validation

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, validation, ip

I'm refactoring my code and wanted to use the [`IPAddress.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx) method to validate if a string is a valid IPv4 address instead of using regular expressions:

```
public static bool IsIPv4(string value)
{
    IPAddress address;

    if (IPAddress.TryParse(value, out address))
    {
        if (address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

My unit test is now failing because these input values return `true` and get parsed to the following `IPAddress` objects:

```
value = "0.0.0.0"      ->  address = {0.0.0.0}
value = "255.255.255"  ->  address = {255.255.0.255}
value = "65536"        ->  address = {0.1.0.0}
```

Does this make sense? I can see that [`0.0.0.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655723/is-0-0-0-0-a-valid-ip-address) is technically a valid IPv4 address, even if it makes no sense for the user to enter that. What about the other two? Why are they converted in the way they are and should I treat them as valid even if it might not be transparent for the user, who maybe just forgot to enter the periods (`65536` instead of `6.5.5.36`).

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: The last one is a conversion from base-256 number, which is a valid representation of an ip address.  There is a known url-hiding scheme where you use that number, something like `http://65536`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the docs for [`IPAddress.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx) rationalize this behavior by pointing out that entering fewer parts is convenient for entering class A and B addresses.  If you want to force a four-part address, you might just want to check that there are three periods in the address before feeding it to `IPAddress.TryParse`, I guess.

Some code for your reference:

```
// verify that IP consists of 4 parts
if (value.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length == 4)
{
    IPAddress ipAddr;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse(value, out ipAddr))
    {
        // IP is valid
    }
    else
        // invalid IP
}
else
    // invalid IP
```

Comment: Try using this,
ValidIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";

Answer (score 21):

The job of IPAddress.TryParse() is not to check if the string *is* a valid IP address, but whether or not the content of the string can be *parsed* (i.e.; converted) to a valid IP address.

All of the options in your test cases can in fact be parsed to represent and IP. What it comes down to is that your test cases are valid. The issue is that the data for your test cases are not valid, or you're not using the right tool(s) in your test case to get the expected result.

If you're specifically testing for a valid IPv4, with exactly 4 quads (each being an integer between 0 - 255), and want to avoid regex your could instead split then parse and validate.

```
public static bool IsIPv4(string value)
{
    var octets = value.Split('.');

    // if we do not have 4 octets, return false
    if (octets.Length!=4) return false;

    // for each octet
    foreach(var octet in octets) 
    {
        int q;
        // if parse fails 
        // or length of parsed int != length of octet string (i.e.; '1' vs '001')
        // or parsed int < 0
        // or parsed int > 255
        // return false
        if (!Int32.TryParse(octet, out q) 
            || !q.ToString().Length.Equals(octet.Length) 
            || q < 0 
            || q > 255) { return false; }

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: good solution, but this would be a little easier to read: if (quads.Length !=4) return false;

Comment: Instead of "quad," the Wikipedia article for [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations) uses the term "octet."

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be very strict about your input, then you can compare the `ToString()` version of the parsed `IPAddress`, and reject the input if they are different.

The all-zero address, and other such things, would have to be handled as special cases.

Comment: And even in the case where four octets are specified, `ToString()` may yield a result that is different from the original representation. For instance, an octet that begins with one or more `0`'s is treated as an octal number. To illustrate, in an example lifted from the [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations) article on Wikipedia, `ToString()` converts `0300.0000.0002.0353` to its decimal equivalent `192.0.2.235`. So, some may find that the use of `ToString()` offers some advantages over simply checking for four octets.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest:

```
    public bool IsValidIp(string addr)
    {
        IPAddress ip;
        bool valid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(addr) && IPAddress.TryParse(addr, out ip);
        return valid;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It only adds a null check to the problem's scope.

Comment: This is what exactly he was asking about, comon read the question atleast

Comment: No, it isn't... at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
    public static bool IsIPv4(string ipAddress)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(ipAddress, @"^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}$") &&
            ipAddress.Split('.').SingleOrDefault(s => int.Parse(s) > 255) == null;
    }
```

Other answers either allow IPv6 or allow input like "1.-0.1.1".

Comment: I like this one, but it throws an exception from SingleOrDefault if you specify an invalid ip address like 10.300.400.10.  I changed it to FirstOrDefault to fix...

Answer (score 2):

The number of parts (each part is separated by a period) in ipString determines how the IP address is constructed. A one part address is stored directly in the network address. A two part address, convenient for specifying a class A address, puts the leading part in the first byte and the trailing part in the right-most three bytes of the network address. A three part address, convenient for specifying a class B address, puts the first part in the first byte, the second part in the second byte, and the final part in the right-most two bytes of the network address. For example:

Number of parts and example ipString
 IPv4 address for IPAddress

1 -- "65536"
 0.0.255.255

2 -- "20.2"
 20.0.0.2

2 -- "20.65535"
 20.0.255.255

3 -- "128.1.2"
 128.1.0.2

You may want to refer MSDN documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx

Your best bet will be IPAddress.ToString() or regular expressions.

Comment: I have a valid regular expressions method. For whatever reason I thought refactoring to `IPAddress.TryParse` is more elegant, but actually it seems more confusing ;)

Comment: There's a typo in the MSDN documentation. `65536` parses to `0.1.0.0`. `65535` to `0.0.255.255`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are valid addresses.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations for more information.

Comment: From there, I don't see how the 2nd example parses to the result mentioned `value = "255.255.255"  ->  address = {255.255.0.255}` Specifically why is the 3rd octet zeroed out instead of either the first or the last?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question was answered like two years ago, I think it is relevant to bring up what I figured out when I was looking for the same thing today, and after finding this page decided I was far too lazy to go through all the validation progmatically.

If the information is being accepted through a `Form` and a `TextBox`, it would be in your best interest to use a `MaskedTextBox` instead. You can force the user to put in information in IP Address format instead of having to do the guesswork yourself.

The mask to be used for such validation is `990.990.990.990` which says `OptionalNumber, OptionalNumber, MandatoryNumber` because `1.1.1.1`, `10.10.10.10`, and `123.123.123.123` are all valid IP Address formats. The masks are the same format that Microsoft uses in Access.

Comment: I agree that masked text boxes are a good idea when you can control the user input at the UI level. Anyhow the question was more focused on why `IPAddress.TryParse` is behaving in the described way.

Comment: But won't the mask that you advocate accept `321.321.321.321`? This would be problematic because no octet in an IPv4 address can exceed the decimal value 255.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, as 65536 is equal to 0x00010000, or 0.1.0.0. I'm guessing TryParse will also accept hex numbers. In any case, I don't think that you'd want to accept such a value from a normal user, but I suppose that depends on the end user.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is using regex, suggested by **Roshe**

```
        string txt = textBox1.Text;

        string ValidIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9‌​]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";    // IP validation 

        Regex r = new Regex(ValidIpAddressRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match m = r.Match(txt);

        if (!m.Success)
        {
          //Not a valid IP
        }

        else
        {


          //A valid IP

        }
```