# MySQL select based on regular expression

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I need to select all rows where a field is not an IP address (e.g. 12.32.243.43). Can this be done with MySQL only?

For example: I tried the following but it doesn't match.

```
select * from mytable where field not like '%.%.%.%'
```

Comment: Google search: "mysql regex" or "mysql regular expression". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Better yet, teach him how to fish: http://bit.ly/J1gsG1

Answer (score 2):

Sure can. You would be looking for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NOT( some_field REGEXP '^[0-9+]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9+]\.[0-9+]')
```

Comment: regexp cannot cover invalid ip address though: 12.32.243.299

Comment: @MichaelBuen:  It *can*, but not very elegantly: `^(([01]\d{0,2}|2[0-4]?\d?|25[0-5]|[3-9]\d?)\.){3}([01]\d{0,2}|2[0-4]?\d?|25[0-5]|[3-9]\d?)$`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655723/is-0-0-0-0-a-valid-ip-address

Answer (score 2):

If using regular expression is not a requirement, this shall deliver the solution:

```
select stringBasedIp from x
where inet_aton(stringBasedIp) is null;


select stringBasedIp, (inet_aton(stringBasedIp) is null) as isInvalidIp
from x;
```

Sample data:

```
create table x(stringBasedIp varchar(16));

insert into x values
('255.255.255.255'),
('0.0.0.0'),
('0.0.0.300'),
('0.0.0.-1'),
('0.0.0.A'),
('192.168.0.1'),
('400.168.0.1'),
('12.32.243.43'),
('12.32.243.430');
```

Here are the list of invalid ip:

```
STRINGBASEDIP
0.0.0.300
0.0.0.-1
0.0.0.A
400.168.0.1
12.32.243.430
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a4ec/1