# JAX-WS 2.2 and JDK6 with maven

Tags: java, webserver, jax-ws, java-ws

I have a web service  and I'm using the `Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8080")`

Thing is that `JAX-WS 2.0 and 2.1` is affected by an issue that throw a `NullPointerException` when executing `endpoint.stop()`.

The issue is fixed in `2.2` but when adding the dependency in the `pom.xml` publishing fails due to a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;` since I'm using `java 1.6`.

The workaround is to add to the `endorsed` folder some libs. But I want to pack it all in `jar-with-dependencies`. An executable java jar.

Said this, I would be thankful if you help me:

```
Publishing the endpoint in 2.0 or 2.1 listening to all addresses (0.0.0.0)
```

or

```
Configuring dependencies in maven to pack everything using 2.2.x 
but executable with JDK6
```

EDIT:

Requirements are a deliverable jar. A single jar that pack all of the dependencies (2 so far, about a 400k jar).

But if you think that the only way to make it work is to add an external shell script please let me know too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable jar format does not allow for endorsed folders required for JAX-WS replacement (and neither does the Java WebStart launcher apparently).

You need to use something that can construct and execute a *new* "java" command on the fly.  The best way from here is most likely to look for an installer which can run the program directly without needing to install.

What exactly do you need to happen?

---

EDIT: As the requirement is a runnable jar you simply cannot do this with JAX-WS 2.2  Find a workaround with the JAX-WS present in the latest release of the Java version you are targetting.

It is very nice that the JAX-WS stack ship with core Java allowign for very small deployments, but a pain that you cannot easily provide your own.

Note that you can provide your own with Java *5* but then you need to bring your own Endpoint implementation.

Comment: I need either to be able to stop the endpoint, pack my app with 2.2.x and that works with JDK 6 or publish the endpoint in a way that listens to all address 0.0.0.0. Thank you

Comment: I was not thinking _inside_ the program, but _installationwise_.  Why do you need a runnable jar - will a foo.bat file not do?

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was suspecting. Thing is, can I bind to an address that listen for all (localhost, 127.0.0.1, [example] 10.10.10.10)?

Comment: Use 0.0.0.0 as indicated in your question.  You might find http://stackoverflow.com/q/11097189/53897 interesting.

Comment: The issue arises when setting to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Do NOT explicitly add JAX-WS libraries in your pom.xml if you use Java 6.

Comment: I don't, in my pom is only one dependency

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the JAX-WS RI? You could use CXF instead which is a fine JAX-WS implementation and doesn't suffer the same collision problems as the RI.

Edit: You could try  to generate the classes with the RI, but use CXF in the deployment. JAX-WS is a spec after all so it *should* work...

Comment: I did try, but when generating the WS java classes CXF left many blocks larger than the maximum size