# Check for port in use when there are multiple interfaces

Tags: java, tcp, network-programming, serversocket

I know that For TCP, we can only have one application listening on a single port at one time. Now if you had 2 network cards, you could have one application listen on the first IP and the second one on the second IP using the same port number.

Now in this case If I have to check whether a particular port is in use, how do I do that?

My intention is a port should be used by only one application even though there are multiple interfaces. Is it Ok if I list all the interfaces and bind with the port number with all those interfaces in a loop, or is there any better way to do this checking.

Answer (score 5):

> I know that For TCP, we can only have one application listening on a single port at one time.

Except as below.

> Now if you had 2 network cards, you could have one application listen on the first IP and the second one on the second IP using the same port number.

Correct.

> Now in this case If I have to check whether a particular port is in use, how do I do that?

See below.

> My intention is a port should be used my only one application even though there are multiple interfaces. Is it Ok if I list all the interfaces and bind with the port number with all those interfaces in a loop, or is there any better way to do this checking.

Just bind it to `0.0.0.0:port`. In Java that means a null `InetAddress` and a non-zero port number. If there are any applications listening at specific interfaces and the same port number, you will get a `BindException`. Conversely, if you are first, it will preclude any other applications from binding to that port in any way at all.

Comment: I guess this relates to only IPv4 address... what if there are IPv6 address? can I see any example as well

Comment: A null `InetAddress` works for IPv6 as well as IPv4 in Java. I don't know what makes you guess otherwise.

Comment: I just read here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11110685/134713 and am getting some doubts about ipv6

Comment: Have you actually *tried* a null `InetAddress`? Or are you just going  to keep reading and accumulating 'doubts' forever?

Comment: NB there is nothing in your link about using a null `InetAddress` *at all,* let alone anything that says it won't work in IPv6.