# In my Java program, why is IP6 involved when I bind to 0.0.0.0?

Tags: java, networking

Disclaimer: networking is not my strong suit.  This may be a very basic question.

Why, when I bind a socket to `0.0.0.0`, does Java also bind to the equivalent of `::` (IP6)?  I thought that `0.0.0.0`, being in dotted quad notation, represents "any IP4 address", not "any IP address, 4 and/or 6".

I'm aware of the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` system property setting, but I'm not asking about that.  I'm asking specifically why Java interprets `0.0.0.0` as "any address at all, IP4 or IP6".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11110685/514463

Comment: Well, this answer is actually exactly my question: it states that "Using 0.0.0.0 will only bind to IPv4-enabled interfaces."  But of course my question is that given that this is demonstrably false for Java programs, why?

Comment: Or, in StackOverflow link parlance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655796/208288 :-)

Comment: In that question, there is also another answer that says binding to 0.0.0.0 binds to all addresses, if you tested it, and that is indeed the case, I suggest you upvote that one

Comment: I understand that it does indeed do this in a Java program.  My question is why, given that `0.0.0.0` is supposed to bind only to IP4 addresses, not IP6 addresses.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/