# Example of a rmi program involving 2 machine connected via LAN

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to learn concepts of rmi in java. I succesfully run it in my machine and tried out to do it on two machine but failed.
Server.java has

```
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        Addition Hello = new Addition();    
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(5432);
        //Addition stub = (Addition) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Hello,6789);
        registry.rebind("lookupthis", Hello);
        System.out.println("Addition Server is ready.");
```

Client.java has

```
Registry reg=LocateRegistry.getRegistry("[ip of server]",5432);
            hello = (AdditionalInterface)Naming.lookup("lookupthis");
            int result=hello.Add(9,10);
            System.out.println("Result is :"+result);
```

What changes i have to make it work for two machines.

Please help me with this, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the server code still explicitly binding to only its loopback address?

Comment: Yes, shall i change the localhost to to [ip of client]?

Comment: Just check the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of "localhost" use "0.0.0.0" in RMI host of the RMI Server.

**EDIT1**

Here are another set of changes:

- Create a registry at the port where you want your server to listen to `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port)`
- Your RMI class `Addition` should be Serializable ( achieved via `UnicastRemoteObject` )
- The RMI methods should throw `RemoteException` in their signature.
- The RMI client should know the name/port of the remote machine ( in this case `box01` / `1091` ).

Also note that the port you chose should not be already occupied by any other service. Such as port `1099`.

Below is the code that works:

**AdditionalInterface.java**

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface AdditionalInterface extends Remote {
    public int Add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**Addition.java**

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Addition extends UnicastRemoteObject implements
        AdditionalInterface {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Addition() throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int Add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

**AdditionServer.java**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

public class AdditionServer {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws RemoteException {
        Addition Hello = new Addition();

        int port = 1091;

        try { // special exception handler for registry creation
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            System.out.println("java RMI registry created.");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // do nothing, error means registry already exists
            System.out.println("java RMI registry already exists.");
        }

        String hostname = "0.0.0.0";

        String bindLocation = "//" + hostname + ":" + port + "/Hello";
        try {
            Naming.bind(bindLocation, Hello);
            System.out.println("Addition Server is ready at:" + bindLocation);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Addition Serverfailed: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**AdditionClient**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.*;

public class AdditionClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String remoteHostName = "box01";
        int remotePort = 1091;
        String connectLocation = "//" + remoteHostName + ":" + remotePort
                + "/Hello";

        AdditionalInterface hello = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to client at : " + connectLocation);
            hello = (AdditionalInterface) Naming.lookup(connectLocation);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        int result = 0;
        try {
            result = hello.Add(9, 10);
        } catch (RemoteException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Result is :" + result);

    }
}
```

Comment: Addition Serverfailed: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a valid target IP address. The bind URL should use 'localhost' and the lookup URL should use the server hostname. There is no requirement for remote objects to be Serializable. Clients connect to servers, not to other clients. -1

Comment: @EJP: 0.0.0.0 is a valid IP address which means `default route address`. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655723/is-0-0-0-0-a-valid-ip-address

Comment: The link you cite quotes RFC 1700 as saying that 0.0.0.0 is only valid as a source address; there is nothing there that says it is a valid target address that resolves to the local host; and there is nothing in the question that requires the default route address.

Comment: @EJP All zeroes is used by every IP stack I know of to mean "listen for connections on all interfaces". Using localhost means that the server will only accept connections from itself.

Comment: @chrylis Exactly so. That's a source address. This answer is using it as a target address, as the address of the RMI Registry to bind to. Do read the answer we're talking about.

Comment: @tuxdna Hi, I saw your result which is awesome but it doesnt work on two vm(s), it does work only on host and vm. Do you know what the problem?