# ipadm to set ip address of an interfce as 0.0.0.0

Tags: solaris

Is there any command or option in ipadm command to set the ip addres as 0.0.0.0
in solaris 11.

when I tried to create ip address using the command ipadm, getting the below error.

## ipadm create-addr -T static -a 0.0.0.0/0 net0/v4

ipadm: cannot create address: Invalid address

Answer (score 1):

The address `0.0.0.0` is an IPv4 *reserved* address, so you may not assign it to an interface. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses as well as https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655736/2299087 for more details.

Why do you want to create an interface with this address, anyway?