# I cannot set an SSH password and hostname for Vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I have a Vagrant file looks like the one below.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.ssh.host = "0.0.0.0"
  config.ssh.password = "foo"
end
```

I want to access to my box via an SSH tool. When I try to connect it with a command like `ssh vagrant@0.0.0.0:22`, I encounter with an error that says `ssh: Could not resolve hostname 0.0.0.0:22: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`
.

According to Vagrant documents, it is possible to set a hostname and password by setting `host` and `password` properties of `ssh` object of the `config`.

I am sure that the current Vagrant box is up and running. I can even access apache via port `80` if I set `forwarded_port` attribute.

`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"`

Comment: Did you actually set 0.0.0.0, or is this just a example to not put the real address here  ? Because if you did it won't work since 0.0.0.0 is a reserved address, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655723/is-0-0-0-0-a-valid-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid `ssh` command line syntax. Use the `-p` command line parameter to specify the port. For example:

This works: `ssh -p 2222 -i /path/to/identity/file vagrant@localhost`
[image: correct command line syntax]

This does not: `ssh -i /path/to/identity/file vagrant@localhost:2222`
[image: incorrect command line syntax]

**Note**: port 22 is the default port for `ssh`, if you're attempting to connect to port 22 then you don't have to specify the port.