# az cil vnet --dns-servers

Tags: azure, dns, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network

I have a problem with using --dns-servers flag in az cli.
When I try to update more than one DNS server it gets broken

```
az network vnet update \
    --name $VNET_name \
    --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION \
    --resource-group $RGRP_name \
    --dns-servers "${LOCATION[3]} ${LOCATION[4]}"
```

the output:

```
IP address is not valid '0.0.0.1 0.0.0.2'
```

The MS documentation says:

```
--dns-servers
        Space-separated list of DNS server IP addresses.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, figured it out somehow.
if you use those vars stright away without closing them withing quotation marks it all works

```
. ./location_arrays
declare -n LOCATION='EM21'
```

...

```
az network vnet create \
    --name $VNET_name \
    --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION \
    --resource-group $RGRP_name \
    --location ${LOCATION[2]} \
    --dns-servers ${LOCATION[-2]} ${LOCATION[-1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try with something like below which I tested in my environment :**

```
$LOCATION = @(
'10.0.0.1',
'10.0.0.2',
'10.0.0.3',
'10.0.0.4'
)
$VNET_name="ansuman-vnet"
$SUBSCRIPTION = "<SubscriptionId>"
$RGRP_name="ansumantest"
az network vnet update --name $VNET_name --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $RGRP_name --dns-servers $LOCATION[2,3]
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS IP addresses '0.0.0.1 0.0.0.2' are not usable as a real IP addresses.

[IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml) states that 0.0.0.0/8 (0...) is reserved as a source address only. You can get into situation where it appears you have this address but that's normally because no address has been assigned to you (by DHCP, for example).

See also [Wikipedia entry on IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4).

Try to set real `--dns-servers` like 8.8.8.8

[Is 0.0.0.0 a valid IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655723/is-0-0-0-0-a-valid-ip-address)

Comment: yes it isn't. they are fake ips. the problem is not in ips themselves but in form i pass them to Azure